# Error in Visual Studio... Extension loading issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I open up VisualStudio 2017 (latest - just updated). I navigate to a type script file (this might just be coincedence that it's this type of file) and I get the following prompt:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension.

You can get more information by examining the file 

'C:\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_c4122470\ActivityLog.xml'
```

In my activity log, I get quite a few **warnings** about packages:

```
Unexpected system error mode before loading package <enter package name here>
```

The real kicker is at the end of the file I get an **error**:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StreamAnalytics.UI.ViewModel.JavaScriptFunctionViewModel.GetJSFunctionInputsCount()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StreamAnalytics.UI.ViewModel.JavaScriptFunctionViewModel.Initialize(JSFunctionInfo configInfo)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StreamAnalytics.UI.ViewModel.JavaScriptFunctionViewModel.InitializeForEditor()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StreamAnalytics.UI.ViewModel.JavaScriptFunctionViewModel..ctor(String jsFilePath, Action saveJsFile, Action setJsFileDirty)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.EditorMarginExtension.JavascriptEditorMargin..ctor(IWpfTextViewHost textViewHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.EditorMarginExtension.JavascriptEditorMarginFactory.CreateMargin(IWpfTextViewHost wpfTextViewHost, IWpfTextViewMargin marginContainer)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.ContainerMargin.&lt;AddMargins&gt;b__25_1(IWpfTextViewMarginProvider mp)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.InstantiateExtension[TExtension,TMetadata,TExtensionInstance](Object errorSource, Lazy`2 provider, Func`2 getter)&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

I have tried:

- Clearing the temp folder
- Clearing the Model Cache inside the VS folder
- Updating packages
- Updating extensions

Nothing seems to help. Does anyone have a thought as to what would be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the bug or issue is cause by the back ticks in your JS or TS code, which were present in the files I was working in.

```
` <- back tick
```

Here is a thread in the VS developer community describing the issue and a potential solution.

[NullReferenceException after opening javascript file](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/292990/nullreferenceexception-after-opening-javascript-fi.html?page=1&pageSize=10&sort=votes)

**Solution For Me:**
I had to upgrade to VS version 15.8.1 (For me ,the bug was still in version 15.8.0, which is what I was using when I posted the question). This version just got released.

So far things are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

> Error in Visual Studio… Extension loading issue

According to the error info "An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension.", you can try to [run the VS with safe mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe) using the command: **devenv /safemode**, if it works fine, that means the installed extensions caused this issue. Since I could not know which specified extension causes this issue based on the error log, you can try to remove/uninstall the installed extensions one by one to find the culprit.

Besides, you can also try to run visual studio as administrator and update the Visual Studio 2017 to latest version.

Hope this helps.